# Qt C++ "keine Rückmeldung" - Error in GUI during long calculations

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, responsiveness

I have a question concerning long calculations:

While executing some tasks of my GUI long calculations might be done. This is not a problem, it just takes a while – everything works fine (at least the results are fine).

What bothers me is that after a certain time my GUI doesn't seem to respond: For example my `ProcessBar` that is shown during calculations will not be displayed and in the title bar of my GUI the text *“keine Rückmeldung”* is added (which means something like busy, crashed, etc - sorry I don't know the correct translation which makes it hard for me to find anything in the internet about that issue).

**Is there a possibility to stop that behavior?**

Thank you.

Comment: It would be great if we could examine your code. May be you are allocating megabytes of memory, or the value is too big.

Comment: sorry, this is not possible because the code is very long. Is there a possibility to generally stop this message + behaviour?

Comment: Have a look at https://doc.qt.io/archives/qq/qq27-responsive-guis.html

Comment: You'd probably translate that by "No response". As for your problem, might be because you execute too much commands within a certain step of time. You might want to separate your problem in chunks and make short pauses in between, maybe with a status output or the like. You'd need to make this pause somewhat logical in order to keep it organic.

Comment: You must move your calculations to separate thread, so you won't block GUI thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options. The more efficient one is to put your calculations into another thread (or multiple threads, there are very few single core CPUs in modern PCs). [JSilver's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43607931/1717300) has a few links for you.

However, with threads come multitude of threading related things you must learn and take into account. There's a lot of potential for subtle bugs, if you don't know what you're doing. So I would recommend alternative approach as first step, single-threaded. As a bonus, it'll make moving to multi-threaded solution much easier later.

1. Create a plain sublclass of QObject. Into this QObject, put the state of your calculation as member variables.
2. Write a slot method into above class, which does a small piece of the calculation, then returns. It should do it's thing at most around 50 ms for good user experience. You can just use a fixed number of iterations in your loop, or use `QElapsedTimer` to measure time, or whatever. And then, when called again, the method should continue the calculation again for another 50ms. When calculation completes, the method can for example *emit a signal with the results*.
3. Add a `QTimer` with interval 0. Connect the timeout to the slot method described above. Interval 0 here effectively means, Qt will call the method as often as it can. You want this, because you want the calculation to finish as quickly as possible of course. However, since the method returns very soon, then Qt can do other stuff (update GUI etc), before calling your method again.

Once this works, in single thread, you can then learn to do Qt threading and move the worker object to live in another thread, for potentially increased performance. Also then you will have a single-threaded baseline version to compare to, in case you run into threading problems.

Answer (score 2):

You should outsource your expensive, long-lasting calculations from the GUI-Thread to a worker thread to prevent your GUI from freezing.

Qt-Documentation: [`Threading Basics`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/thread-basics.html)

Good explanation of QThread-usage I found useful: [`How To Really, Truly Use QThreads`](https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/)

The GUI itself cannot be changed from a worker thread. You have to [`notify`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) your main-thread about a data-change and update your GUI from there.